# Providing 1024x1024 App Store icon when building with Ionic

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, app-store, phonegap

I maintain an old phonegap project, that is now built with Ionic (which uses Cordova).
For now, everything seems to work fine, but there is one problem: The iOS App Store icon does not show up, I see the default Cordova icon instead.

[image: Cordova icon]

Since providing the App Store icon with App Store Connect [is not working anymore](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev4b0ebb1bb?sub=dev3c7018a67)
I did add a 1024x1024 icon to the apps resources and the following line to the config.xml:

```html
<icon height="1024" src="resources/icons/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
```

But that did not help. I still see the wrong icon when I upload to the store. Everything else works fine, once you downloaded the app, you can see the right icon on your homescreen.

Any ideas?

Comment: <icon height="1024" src="resources/iOS/icons/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />

Comment: @Arasuvel So I have to create a seperate iOS folder for my iOS resources to make Cordova recognize the icon? That's it?